# Why are all classes showing up twice in dotCover results in TeamCity?

Tags: teamcity, dotcover

Using TeamCity 9.0.2, I have an Nunit build step with the following configuration:

**Run tests from:** **\*.Tests.dll
**Do not run tests from:** **\obj\**\*.dll
**.NET Coverage Tool:** JetBrains dotCover
**Filters:** -:MyAssembly.Tests (along with several namespaces in primary assembly to exclude)

After I run the build, the code coverage report shows every class twice, with the exact same output/statistics for both.  For example:
Class1   100%(2/2)  100% (20/20) 75% (75/100)
Class1   100%(2/2)  100% (20/20) 75% (75/100)
Class2   100%(4/4)  100% (30/30) 80% (120/150)
Class2   100%(4/4)  100% (30/30) 80% (120/150)

Has anyone else seen the same behavior?  If so, what can you suggest to resolve the issue?

Comment: I’m afraid without logs it will be impossible to find the cause of the problem. If you add the ‘teamcity.agent.dotCover.log’ configuration parameter to the build configuration with a path to an empty directory on the agent, all dotCover log files will be placed there and TeamCity will publish zipped logs as hidden build artifact: ‘.teamcity/.NETCoverage/dotCoverLogs.zip’.  Please send the logs to this e-mail address: support@jetbrains.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two different build configurations that can be run on the same build agent, you may get two similar test assemblies that match the ‘***.Tests.dll’ pattern, for example. As a result, coverage report may contain duplicate data.

You can either specify target assemblies in your build step more precisely (Build Steps | Run tests from) or clean the corresponding checkout directory before the build (Version Control Settings | Clean all files in the checkout directory before the build).

Comment: Thanks Maria.  I tried both those approaches independently and they both work.